# Oracle on Azure closes connection after a time period

Tags: azure, batch-file, oracle11g

We have a Oracle 11g DB on Microsoft Azure VM.

1. The oracle connection at client side closes after a time period even if active sqls are running. I'm checking active sql reports one minute and in the next BOOM closed connection.
   We have not defined any profile and timing out a connection but still if I keep a connection in my SQL Developer and some time later when i run a query, The connection is closed.
2. In case of running batch programs which consume more time on the server itself, It seems to get hanged and no session will exist of this batch program
   I'm guessing after a particular time from getting a session, the DB is closing the connection thus making the batch hang.

Is it related to Azure or any other thing. It is not even producing any error codes

Comment: I am afraid you will need to explain it bit more than that..

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I have added more details